# Java Reflection and Singleton

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

Why reflection cannot break singleton pattern through breaking the private constructor through below code. There should be a new Instance on InstanctTwo but there is not.

```
Constructor[] constructors = EagerInitializedSingleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
  //Below code will destroy the singleton pattern
  constructor.setAccessible(true);
  instanceTwo = (EagerInitializedSingleton) constructor.newInstance();
  break;
}
```

Comment: Sure it can.  Why do you think it can't?

Comment: Can it if `EagerInitializedSingleton` is an `enum`? (It doesn't sound like it is, but we don't actually have the code). I ask because of what Josh Bloch says about the "ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or reflection attacks"

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception while printing hash for instanceTwo. EagerInitializedSingleton is a singleTon as name suggests. This is not enum.

Comment: Does the fact that you are getting exceptions when you try to break an invariant of the class maybe imply that you shouldn't try to do that?

Comment: I can invoke the constructor from first line and based on documentation, setAccessible(true)  should do what I want and there is no such exception.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work if `EagerInitializedSingleton` is an enum. (I make no comment about whether it works in other cases)

```
class Ideone
{
    enum EagerInitializedSingleton { INSTANCE }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Constructor[] constructors = EagerInitializedSingleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
        for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
          //Below code will destroy the singleton pattern
          constructor.setAccessible(true);
          System.out.println((EagerInitializedSingleton) constructor.newInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/QgRLvT)

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot reflectively create enum objects
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
>     at Ideone.main(Main.java:19)
> ```

Comment: Its not enum. Its a singleton class and I am using eager-initialization as name suggests.

Comment: An enum *is* an eagerly-initialized singleton.

Comment: Ok. But the class is not enum. Its a singleton class and I would like to break private constructor to create one more instance.

Comment: If it's a singleton class, why do you want a second instance?

Comment: I want the class to be singleton unless the special case when I need to break private constructor.

Comment: A singleton which is not singleton in special cases is not a singleton. Change the class so it is not a singleton, or work with it as a singleton. Using hacks and bodges to force it to be something it is not is not the right approach.